# Как задать параметр для метода?

Tags: java

Хочу чтобы в метод моего интерфейса можно было передать класс, который реализует интерфейс Serializable.

К примеру:

```
 interface myInterface {
    
        <T implemets Serializable> void myEvent(T object) {}
    
 } // это, конечно, не работает


 public class A implements Serializable {...}
 public class B implements Serializable {...}
```

Я хочу обозначить, что для метода myMethod в качестве параметра подойдёт любой класс реализующий Serializable. Как это сделать?

Comment: `void myMethod(Serializable s);`

Answer (score 2):

Обозначить тип параметра в методе можно несколькими способами:

1. Использовать `Serializable` непосредственно в сигнатуре метода как указал в комментарии @Stanislav Volodarskiy:

```java
public SimpleInterface {
    void myMethod(Serializable ser);
}
```

Это наиболее простой и логичный способ.

2. Использовать эквивалентный обобщённый метод (почти как указано в коде вопроса):

```java
public GenMethodInterface {
    <T extends Serializable> void myMethod(T t);
}
```

3. Использовать обобщённый интерфейс (если нужна дополнительная проверка типов):

```java
public GenInterface<T extends Serializable> {
    void myMethod(T t);
}
```

В данном случае нужно будет создать типизированный экземпляр интерфейса:

```java
GenInterface<Serializable> gi = new GenInterface<>() { // Java 9+
    @Override public void myMethod(Serializable s) {
        // ... реализация
    }
};
```